# Setup Help with multiple routers

Tags: router, switch, ethernet, network-discovery

I'm trying to expand the wireless network in my church and am having some issues. I'm not a networking expert so I'd appreciate some input.

Here's our setup:

1. AT&T/Motorola Gateway (NVG589) 
   Seems to function as both modem and a router/access point, but wireless broadcasting has been turned off on this device. 
   Connected to a 24 port switch via Ethernet 
   Connected to an office router from the DSL port on the NVG589
   Generates IP: 192.168.**1**.254
2. ASUS router (RT-AC87U) 
   Serves wireless for building 1. 
   When wire from NVG589 is fed to Asus' WAN port, it has to create a new IP. e.g. 192.168.**2**.1 - now devices that are connected directly to the switch cannot be seen by devices wirelessly connected to the router. This is a problem. 
   If wire from NVG589 is fed to a LAN port in the router, same IP is given, all devices can be seen, but now cannot access admin GUI for router.
3. We have 2 other routers in another building that are having the same issue as above. 
   When the wire from the switch is plugged into the WAN port, I can access admin and can get online, but I can't see the devices that are hardwired to the switch or that are on the other routers. 
   When the wire from the switch is plugged into a LAN port, I can get online and can see all other devices successfully, but now I have no access to the router admin.

So I feel like I'm almost there but now I have no access to the router admin page/features.

What is the correct/best way to make all this work?

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is not completely clear*

You need to configure each router such that it has an IP address on the same network. You should setup each one individually before connecting them up. You may also need to configure DHCP so that clients do not get assigned IP addresses that you wish to use for the routers.

```
NVG589
  address: 192.168.1.254
  netmask: 255.255.255.0

RT-AC87U
  address: 192.168.1.253
  netmask: 255.255.255.0
  gateway: 192.168.1.254    (if required)
```

Then you can connect them with using the LAN ports (on both). You should will be able access all devices and the GUI of each device (use the IP address you've assigned).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After initially setting up the network, I realized I needed to change the IP of the router like you demonstrated. But when I would try to change the IP of the router, it would give me an error saying that the "WAN and LAN should have different IP addresses and subnet". WAN is set to automatic IP so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You can just set the WAN subnet to something else (within the allowed private ranges). For example you could set it on the `192.168.99.0` network with IP address `192.168.99.1`. You won't be accessing the WAN side of that router once everything is setup.